# Magento FedEx Module

Tags: module, magento-1, fedex

We're building a Magento site for a client, but we've bumped into a major issue. The client is asking us to install a FedEx shipping module, but we can't integrate it with our store as they have informed us that FedEx don't ship in our country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento contains in the core [FedEx as a shipping carrier](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php).
You don't need to install anything, you just need to configure it from `system->shipping methods`.
But I don't think there is a solution if FedEx does not ship in your country.
The core module is integrated with the FedEx API. The delivery settings are set to the API and the shipping methods and costs are retrieved. If they don't ship in your country then you won't get back any costs and the user will not be able to select FedEx as a carrier.

Comment: @marius : How can i configure fedex display shipping cost based weight  and location